# Does standing on a contested Capture Point make a difference?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Does it matter if you are standing on an abandoned, but contested capture point?
Will the progress bar go down faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, but only in specific cases.

The enemy's 'Capture Progress' bar will only deteriorate faster if the point is currently in a state where it can be captured by your team (in other words, only 'Neutral' points). If you are standing on a point your team owns that the enemy tried (and failed) to capture, you will not increase the decay of their capture attempt:

> #### Reverting capture
>
> When both teams are trying to capture a neutral point, captures can be reverted. If a team begins to capture a neutral point and then is driven off before capture is completed, the other team must first "revert" the progress that the first team had made before they can begin to make progress of their own.
>  <sub>- [TF2 Wiki: Control Point (Game Mode)](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Control_Point_(game_mode)#Reverting_capture)</sub>

In other words, to capture a neutral point, you need to 'undo' the enemy team's progress bar before your own team's progress will start.